# Contacting a user

Tags: support, comments

I wanted to make a comment on a question, but I don't have enough rep to make a comment but what I want to say is not an answer to the question. So how can I go about getting my comment to the person who asked the question?

Answer (score 6):

You wait until you have enough reputation to comment.

That's it. It's not a high bar to get to that reputation level (you're nearly there already!).

If the person is active in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), you can try there. You have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: @JoeyD473 By "active", wax eagle means this person has used the chat recently. If so, writing @ followed by his name will cause a notification to appear on his bar just like the one you received for this message. If you don't see an autocomplete when typing his name, the user has not been in that chat recently enough and will not get a notification.